# Capture spaces in wrapped characters and remove them, probably with RegEx

Tags: regex, string, edit

I have this so far: https://regexr.com/511fs but it is not capturing inside [ ] only, I probably know why but haven't found a better way to do it at the moment.

Example string I have:

`<s f x> <n o r e p e a t : 1> [ S h a t t e r i n g   G l a s s ]   <s f x> <n o r e p e a t : 1> [ S h a t t e r i n g   G l a s s ]   <s f x> <n o r e p e a t : 1> [ B r e a k i n g   C e r a m i c s ]   <s f x> <n o r e p e a t : 1> [ S h a t t e r i n g   c e r a m i c s ]   <s f x> <n o r e p e a t : 1> [ S h a t t e r i n g   m o n i t o r ]   <s f x> [ M e l o n   S p l a t ]   <s f x> [ M e l o n   S p l a t ]`

I'm trying to basically, right now I'm trying to remove spaces only inside the brackets `[]`. But I'm failing and need help on how to do so, I haven't found a way to do it.

It seems like that every letter has a space infront and after it which I'm trying to remove.

The out come should be this as example:

`[Shattering Glass]`

but with the other things means it would look like this, that's the end result

`<sfx> <norepeat:1> [Shattering Glass]`

as example.

Is RegEx good for that, I'm using online tools. Or is there another easy way?

Comment: What is the tool/language you are planning to use?

Comment: I don't know, currently I've found https://www.browserling.com/tools/regex-replace. If you know another site, make sure to let me know if it's good.

Comment: You should use a normal language for that. Then, in C#, you may use `Regex.Replace(text, @"\[[^][]+]|<[^<>]+>", m=>m.Value.Replace(" ",""))`. There are equivalent solutions in other languages

Comment: Ok, what about https://regex101.com/r/xMX2EB/1? Will it do?

Answer (score 0):

In a regex tester that supports PCRE regex, you may use

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|[[<])[^][<>\s]*\K\s+(?=[^][<>]*[]>])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xMX2EB/2).

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|[[<])` - either the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!\A)`) or (`|`) a `[` or `<` char (`[[<]`)
- `[^][<>\s]*` - any 0+ chars other than `]`, `[`, `<`, `>` and whitespace
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far from the match memory buffer
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?=[^][<>]*[]>])` - immediately to the right, there must be 0+ chars other than `]`, `[`, `<`, `>` and then `>` or `]`.